# How can I apply the XSLT identity Pattern to a particular node within a document?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML Document to be transformed using XSLT, I dont want to use the Identity pattern for whole of the document but just one element in the document. e.g. at  i want to apply identity pattern. any ideas?

Comment: Without an example of your code it's harder to tell you what to do.  An identity template applies only if no other, more specific template applies, so just make sure all other elements are handled by a more-specific template and invoke the identity at the proper place for your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do a deep copy of a single node unchanged while applying other templates at other places, just use the `<xsl:copy-of>` at the appropriate point in your stylesheet.